# Using notepad++ to run python, yet it gives me a syntax error even though it is correct

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm using python 27 and the code was

```
print "HI".
```

I used

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

to get notepad++ to work with python if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

You have a full stop *outside* of the string:

```
print "HI".
   # -----^
```

That is not legal Python:

```
>>> print "HI".
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "HI".
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Remove that or move it *into* the string:

```
print "HI."
```